# Look in direction of 2d Vector

Tags: c#, math, 2d

I am trying to make a simple application that turns a character to look at a vector relative to it's current position.

The rotation value ranges from 0 - 180 and -180 - 0.

Math is not my strong point and I'd appreciate it if C# code examples could be explained, I need a value to set into the rotation variable in the ranges mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Atan2()` function to convert relative *x*, *y* position into angles

```
        double dx=target.X-actor.X;
        double dy=target.Y-actor.Y;
        double angle=Math.Atan2(dy, dx)*180/Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 1):

The angle can be calculated by translating the vector to polar notation (r, theta): 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

To get theata from x and y, you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx

Cheers.

Comment: You pass the x, y values of your var, and the atan2 function does all the work (you need to convert from degrees to radians by multiplying by 180/pi). You can always make your math better, try the khan academy :)